# Here I want to add button value in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add button value in text box. When I select "call", the value will be "call" in textbox and suppose when I select "meeting", the value will be "meeting" in textbox.

My problem is, when I select the value is coming multiple and also page is redirecting. I could not find solution.
Thanks in advanced.

My code:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveValue(num) {
    var txt = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    txt = txt + num;
    document.getElementById("subject").value = txt;
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control holiday_name"  name="holiday_name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group row">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Call" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;Call</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Meeting" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-group"></i>&nbsp;Meeting</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Task" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp;Task</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Deadline" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>&nbsp;Deadline</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Email" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Email</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Lunch" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>&nbsp;Lunch</button>

                </div>
```

Comment: For a limited choice of fixed values, you should perhaps just be using a `select` field in the first place …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to remove the submit attribute in the buttons, so it won't redirect the page, here is a working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/yrpwop7o/1/

And the correct version of the javascript code is:

```
window.moveValue = function(num) {
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
    subject.value = num;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is, when I select the value is coming multiple and also page is redirecting.

Because you *submit* the form. Note, that you have buttons as type `submit`. Change them to just `button` and it will not attempt to send form for server processing.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Call" onclick="moveValue(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;Call</button>
```

Comment: Just wondering why you have `type="type"` in your code. Shouldn't the `type` attribute be omitted entirely?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `type="button"`. If you drop type attribute it will fallback to submit by default again.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the correct attribute for an `input`? I.e `<input type="button" ....` The button element is just that, isn't it - i.e a button.

Comment: @enhzflep `<button>` element also has attribute `type` with value `button` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: Both button and input have type attribute which can be button or submit.

Comment: @dfsq : You right..I did so silly mistake. Thank you.
But can you give suggestion for value of button which would insert in textbox. 
Currently all button value is inserting one by one.

Comment: *"But can you give suggestion for value of button which would insert in textbox. Currently all button value is inserting one by one."*. Can you elaborate a little here?

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the value of **subject** as ***num*** which is passing from the **onclick** event.

```js
function moveValue(num) {
  var txt = document.getElementById("subject").value;
  //txt = txt + num; //remove this line because it will bind the values
  document.getElementById("subject").value = num;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject<span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control holiday_name" name="holiday_name" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Call" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;Call</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Meeting" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-group"></i>&nbsp;Meeting</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Task" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp;Task</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Deadline" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>&nbsp;Deadline</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Email" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Email</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" value="Lunch" onclick="moveValue(this.value);"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>&nbsp;Lunch</button>

</div>
```